# publish and deploying .net core application to linux

Tags: windows-10, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-webapi

Im having truble with publish and deploying a .net core web-api on a ubuntu 16.04 desktop ran in vmware. I have developed a simple web-api application with almost no extra implementation from the template v1.1. I have been installing and using some dependencies that are runnable in .net core.

Problem:
Im using framework dependent release v1.1.
I can launch a released version on windows by using "dotnet publish -c release" and it works fine. I then move the published files to my ubuntu machine and tries to run it I get the error that it cannot locate some kind of assembly that I know is in the dll folder.

However if I move the source code and project to my ubuntu machine and do a "dotnet restore" and "dotnet publish -c release" the application works. If I dont use the "dotnet restore" and tries to publish on my ubuntu machine it gets another "are you missing an assembly reference".

My guess is that when I do "dotnet publish -c release" it targets runtimes only for windows or ubuntu depending on the machine publishing.

Im grateful for help and explanation for this.

Sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me have been running the wrong application dll. I always ran the application dll in the folder netcoreapp1.1 when I should have ran the same dll in the sub directory publish.